# I am not understanding functions after studying it?

Tags: jquery, function

After asking questions dealing with functions for a couple of days and getting the good result I am still missing something because once I try to functions on my own I always do something wrong.  Here is my main issue.

This code is what I got that works fine with the help of people from this site.

```
$(document) .ready(function(){
        $('.port').hide();

        $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.port').show();
        });

        $('.click').click(function(){
         $('.bio').animate({left:'15em'}, 2500);
        $('.web').animate({left:'12.5em', top:'6.5em'}, 3500);
        $('.resume').animate({top:'5.3em', left:'25px'},2500);
        $('.social').animate({top:'.5em', left:'25px'}, 2500);   
        });

        $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.click').fadeOut(3000, function(){$('.name').fadeIn(); }).css({backgroundColor: rgba(59,207,119,.2)});    
        });

    });
```

What I realize some new functions are used after a previous one and its divided by });.   However, in the last click functions, there is a function within the fadeout.  I thought that made sense because I wanted the animation to happen all with one "click"

At this point I am trying to add a new function where I click (.bio),(.web) and (.social) and a "diplay:none" div.  So I added

```
$('.bio).click(function(){
 $('.thedisplay:nonediv').show().animate(......);
});
```

After the last function and before the ready() end brackets and it does not work. After studying and getting help, i assume that this is the way I write a new function.  I hope that this answer will help understand the format of functions.  Thanks

Comment: I am trying to understand what your question is and what you are trying to do but I can not make sense of it. Can you rewrite your question?

Comment: Basically I am confused with where to add a new function() and when I should use a new one. Sometimes I see that its fit to use to add a function within one. I am confused with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to having a number of anonymous functions all based on the click event on ".click" - you can combine them and if a function affects ".click" itself - you can use $(this).... since it is referencing the triggering element. Also don't have a space between the $(document) and the .ready(...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.port').hide();

    $('.click').click(function(){
        $('.port').show();
        $('.bio').animate({left:'15em'}, 2500);
        $('.web').animate({left:'12.5em', top:'6.5em'}, 3500);
        $('.resume').animate({top:'5.3em', left:'25px'},2500);
        $('.social').animate({top:'.5em', left:'25px'}, 2500);   
        $(this).fadeOut(3000, function(){$('.name').fadeIn(); }).css({backgroundColor: rgba(59,207,119,.2)});    
     });
 });
```